# hash table/pscustomobject instead of switch block

Tags: hashtable, powershell-3.0

Is there a  way to use hash table or pscustomobject instead of switch block below? hash table seems like a great way to simplify the function.

```
function Get-Farm
{
[cmdletbinding()]
    param (
    [parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$farm)

Process{
        switch($farm){
            A {
                $script:startHostID = 0
                $script:endHostID = 0
            }
            B {
                $script:startHostID = 1
                $script:endHostID = 12
            }
            C {
                $script:startHostID = 13
                $script:endHostID = 24
            }

            BC {
                $script:startHostID = 1
                $script:endHostID = 24
            }

            ALL {
                $script:startHostID = 1
                $script:endHostID =48
            }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, hashtable lookup is a better alternative.
Create the lookup table in `Begin` block and use it in `Process`.
Also, use `ValueFromPipeline` in parameter description, otherwise don't use `Process`.

```ps
function Get-Farm
{
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]$farm
)
Begin {
    $lookup = @{
        A = 0,0
        B = 1,12
        C = 13,24
        BC = 1,24
        ALL = 1,48
    }
}
Process {
    if ($values = $lookup[$farm]) {
        $script:startHostID = $values[0]
        $script:endHostID = $values[1]
    }
}
}
```

I've used the assignment inside `if()` to condense the code but of course you can write it separately:

```ps
$values = $lookup[$farm]
if ($values) {
```